# I need assistance to verify the string with the html

Tags: jquery

I'm confuse how to do this. I want to compare the html with the string if it equal I want the button to be active. and am using jquery. I used ajax to set the #uname_response html

```
$("#validationCode").keyup(function(){
    if($("#uname_response").html == "VALIDATION CODE IS VALID COMPLETE TRANSFER.") {
        $(':input[id="Transferpage"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
})
```

Comment: You have used method like property, use  $("#uname_response").html()   instead of  
 $("#uname_response").html

Comment: Without knowing what `#uname_response` is, you might want `$("#uname_response").val() ==` or `$("#uname_response").text() ==` or `$("#uname_response").html() ==`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your checking condition is working fine. So, you can use `.removeAttr()` method of the jQuery to remove `disabled` attribute. Read the official [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) here.

**Edit**: Just saw your question again, there is a mistake in your condition. The method for fetching the html contents is `.html();` where you wrote `.html`. If you want to use JavaScript's property, it's `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the *html* content of an element is done with the following method:

```
$("#uname_response").html()
```

If you only want the text within (not the html tags), use `text()` instead of `html()`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parenthesis on $("#uname_response").html as JQuery#html is a function not a property.

HTMLElmement.innertHtml is a property which is returned by the .html() function.

Indeed this is a problem, fix it and let me know if it still doesn't work

Comment: I tried every suggestions non of them work... i guess the problem is that since the html is set with ajax, the jquery function was unable to grab the text. i want to use ajax to see if it work..

Comment: Have you tried to log the result of $("#uname_response").html() after the text is set? Try to log both $("#uname_response") and  $("#uname_response").html()